# Can I build on an easement?

Tags: real-estate, illinois, easement

I live in Jackson County, Illinois. I failed to check if there was an easement before buying my house, and got saddled with a 50-foot-wide ingress/egress easement. I know this is unusual, but it really isn't a utility easement. The owner apparently gave himself the easement when he sold the land to the people I bought the property from.

Can I build a duck coop on it as long as the easement owner can easily access his property to the north of my house, using the easement? His property north of mine is undeveloped land, that he mows at least once a year. He also has access from the highway next to his parcel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### If it doesn’t cause [substantial interference](https://www.cbp.com.au/insights/insights/2012/february/can-you-build-over-or-under-an-easement) to the easement rights

You need to look at the specific terms of the easement i.e. what right it gives to your neighbour. If you can build your chicken coop in such a way that it doesn’t materially affect those rights, then that’s ok

However, for this type of easement, any ground level structure is likely to interfere with the use of the easement.